# Firefox keeps suggesting usernames, even though I have disabled the default password manager

Tags: firefox, password-management, lastpass

I use LastPass as a password manager. I have disabled Firefox's inbuilt password manager.

[image]

LastPass has only one entry for the site I'm visiting, but Firefox still suggests many different usernames:

[image]

**How do I stop Firefox from suggesting unrelated usernames?**

Comment: And now your e-mail addresses are revealed...

Comment: If you post a version without those email addresses (scribble on them), you can mod flag for edit history redacation.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος I know. My email addresses are available all over the internet. You're welcome to email me. I'll post a redacted version since everyone else seems to keep telling me but it's really not that much of a big deal.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The feature you're seeing is not related to the password manager but rather form data. Check History, change it to "Use custom settings for history" and disable "Remember search and form history" if you really don't want that feature.

This will also disable the suggestion feature for other form types. For example you might have common search terms that won't be available as a quick select anymore or your address and so on.

[image: image of Firefox options]

Comment: Thanks Seth! I've tested this and it works, so the other logins don't show up. Having other stuff like my name / address etc not autocomplete is fine, I have Lastpass to do this.

Comment: There are cases where it might still be inconvenient. As an example if you have some search term you enter every other day in your favorite search engine. Nice if it works for you though. If you're the author of that website you could also check [MDN web docs on autocompletion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion).

Comment: If you have a search term you enter every other day in your favorite search engine you can just bookmark the page of results.